# How to reduce the size of rows having a form?

Tags: html, html-table, row

The size of the row having a html form is larger than size of rows not having . How to reduce the size of rows having a form (row 1 and 2) to be of same size as of rows not having forms (row 3 and 4th). The size of row having form tag is almost twice as that of row not having form tag.

NOTE:  This issues is seen in chrome and forefox on a normal web page. Somehow this issue is not seen in jsfiddle.net.

This link shows the issue :  http://cssdesk.com/ScsXK

Source code :

```
<html>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>one</th> <th>two</th> <th>three</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10</td> <td>10</td>
      <td><form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="CPU"></form></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>20</td> <td>20</td>
      <td><form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="CPU"></form></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td> <td>4</td> <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>6</td> <td>7</td> <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <th width="33%"> on every th tag

Comment: is it row or column? Because the row size (or height) is virtually the same. See here http://jsfiddle.net/Ev7P5/

Comment: By the way why you have a lot table row <tr>  end tag (i.e. </tr> rather than pair of open and close tags, that is, <tr></tr>?

Comment: <tr> issues fixed. This code does not show same size for all rows when see in chrome and forefox. But it works fine in jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing line

```
<td><form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="CPU"</form></td>
```

to

```
<form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><td><input type="submit" value="CPU"></td></form>
```

This now works fine in chrome and firefox.

Ses this link : http://cssdesk.com/zbPjp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>

<body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="33%">one</th> <th width="33%">two</th> <th width="33%">three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td> <td>10</td>
        <td><form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="CPU">    </form></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td> <td>20</td>
        <td><form action="testb.pl" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="CPU"></form></td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> <td>5</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>6</td> <td>7</td> <td>8</td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i changed the anshwer. try it. Actualy you didn't construct the table tags correctly

Comment: i have fixed <tr> and tags issues in the question. Still it does not work in chrome & firefox. When tested in jsfiddle it shows ok.

Comment: Hm, strange. If it works in jsfiddle, and not in local, something in local is not good.

Comment: I want the row size to be same order - so no need to add 33%. See the difference in row sizes - http://cssdesk.com/zbPjp

Comment: width=33% doesnt change the row order. Without that it is normal to have width=auto. So you have to set the row width somehow. If you want to be equal, you should give them equal widths. In this case 33% is the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is row height you could create a css class for the table row like:

```
table.equalheight tr {
line-height:30px;
```

}

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev7P5/1/)

Comment: The code works fine in jsfiddle site But same html does not work when seen in chrome/ firefox on a normal web page. The size of row having <form> is twice as that of row not having <form> tag.